# How to add JAR library to Java project in NetBeans 17 IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, libraries

I try to code in Java with framework Jade so i downloaded proper file (jade.jar). I copied it's path and pasted to system's CLASSPATH. In Apache Netbeans IDE i choose: tools->libraries and then i added the library with correct path to jade.jar and here is all OK, but the jade library is not recognized while coding. I tried to click right mouse button on my project on left side of GUI and i searched option "Add library" or "add JAR file" but something like that doesn't exist: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFdLH.png) So I tried to click on properties from above list, but there is not libraries option: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIBJo.png I clicked also the Files tab above projects list, but there- also is no possibility for finding way to adding jar library to Java project. So please help me, my ideas and founded resolutions in network really ended. Is it possible my version of NetBeans is faulty? I don't think so (i downloaded it from official page) so please explain me what to do.
I want to add, that in this case important for me is how to add a DOWNLOADED JAR file manually to the project in Apache Netbeans, not especially in Maven, where we have pom.xml and for building necessary is network connection. I could find option "Add JAR" nowhere while i was sure that it exists.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I founded the problem's source. In the **Apache Netbeans 17** we may add manually *JAR libraries* but when we create new *Java project* with *Ant* (not Maven or Gradle). After creating this one adding jar libraries is easy, like i wrote above:

`Right mouse button at project in left panel -> properties -> libraries` and now we choose (of course before we have to set the classpath with libraries in tools Netbeans).